# SharePoint Server Farm HDD

Tags: server-farm

SharePoint servers require a 80gb HDD System drive per server per technet. How flexible is that requirment? What are other peoples experience with configuring farm server's hard drives?  http://tjo.me/hFh8SB

Is a secondary partition helpful in anyway or not needed.

Answer (score 1):

As the article describes - logging, memory dumps, object cache, etc. consumes disk space and helps the farm be performant.

Also, 80GB per server isn't much in the scheme of things. You really don't want to have other services running on a SharePoint Server (due to the resource consumption, you want SharePoint to have all it can to help performance, especially so if you have a high number of users). If you have a server capable of running SharePoint 2010, it will be modern enough to have a large amount of disk space.

Having said this, my development systems never really go above 50GB - and that's everything (SharePoint binaries, SQL Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008 R2, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate), 3 web apps, and that's with minimal to no content existing on the servers.